# Test Case for Salesforce to Salesforce Sharing

Tags: force.com

I have built an application that uses Salesforce to Salesforce and have written test cases for the application. I do not determine how to create a test case to  simulate a connection. Below is a streamlined example of the code I would like to write a test case for.

```
 public Id getConnectionId(String connectionName) {

 List<PartnerNetworkConnection> partnerNetConList =
                [Select id from PartnerNetworkConnection where connectionStatus =  'Accepted' and connectionName = :connectionName];

     return partnerNetConList.get(0).Id; }
```

Many Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a mockResponse using `setContinuationResponse(requestLabel, mockResponse)`. See [setMock(interfaceType, instance)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setMock) from the Apex Code Developer's Guide for more on the subject. If you search, you'll find plenty of sample code.